# Tips on solving linear systems for implicit differentation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, self-learning, implicit-differentiation

I have two examples of implicit differentiation:

Example 1:
$x^2+y^2+z^2-6=0$;
$xyz+2=0$

Supposing the both $x$ and $y$ are differentiable functions of $z$, then to compute $\frac{dx}{dz}$ and $\frac{dy}{dz}$ I get:

$$(1)\space\space\space\space 2x\frac{dx}{dz}+2y\frac{dy}{dz}+2z=0$$
$$(2)\space\space\space\space yz\frac{dx}{dz}+xz\frac{dy}{dz}+xy=0$$

How should I approach for solving the implicit differentiation, as I cannot manage to figure it out as I have yet been taught on how to do it, the answer should be for $\frac{dx}{dz}=\frac{x(y^2-z^2)}{z(x^2-y^2)}$?

Then there's also example two which confuses me even further:

$xu+yv+zw=1$;
$x+y+z+u+v+w=0$;
$xy+zuv+w=1$

Supposing that each of $x, y, z$ is a function of $u, v, w$, and differentiating in this case with respect to $w$, I can get linear system:

$$\begin{pmatrix}u & v & w \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ y & x & uv \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_w \\ y_w \\ z_w \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-z \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

And solving this should yield:

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial w} = \frac{uv^2+xz+w-zuv-xwv-v}{u^2v+vy+wx-yw-ux-uv^2}$$

I have thought of converting the left matrix into determinant form which gives me:

$$u^2v-ux-uv^2-vy+wx-wy$$

Which gives some aspects of the solution.

I do apologise as I have been staring at this for an hour and have not been getting close to the solution, your heartening help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Solving linear systems in this case is no different from solving linear systems in general. Just use Gaussian elimination, or perhaps Cramer's rule, or multiply from the left by the inverse of the matrix.

Comment: @HansLundmark I was thinking this! I will give it a go and update my post